Where does the obstruction to infinitesimally extending a morphism from an affine scheme into Hom scheme lie?
I am trying to understand the first section of Mori's 1979 paper on Projective Manifolds with Ample Tangent Bundles. In it, Mori first constructs a scheme $\mathrm{Hom}_S(X, Y; p)$ parametrizing S-morphisms between projective S-schemes X and Y that restrict to a fixed morphism $p: Z \to Y$ for a closed subscheme $Z$, where X and Z are flat over S. Next Mori proves the following:
Proposition: With the set up above, also assume $Y$ is smooth over $S$. Consider an affine $S$-scheme $T = \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and a closed subscheme $\overline{T} = \mathrm{Spec}(A / I)$ such that $I^2 = 0$. Fix $\overline{f}: \overline{T} \to \mathrm{Hom}_{S}(X,Y; p)$. We can view $\overline{f}$ as a morphism $X_{\overline{T}} \to Y_{\overline{T}}$ that restricts to $p_{\overline{T}}: Z_{\overline{T}} \to Y_{\overline{T}}$.Consider the sheaf $\overline{f}^*((T_{Y / S})_{\overline{T}}) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X_{\overline{T}}}} (I_{Z})_{\overline{T}} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X_{\overline{T}}}} I$, where $T_{Y / S}$ is the relative tangent bundle of $Y$ over $S$, and $I_{Z}$ is the ideal sheaf of $Z \subset X$. Then the obstruction to extending $\overline{f}$ to a morphism $T \to \mathrm{Hom}_{S}(X,Y; p)$ lies in $H^1(X_{\overline{T}}, G)$.
My first question is, what precisely does this claim mean? I understand an obstruction to be an element of the cohomology group whose vanishing is a necessary condition to the existence of the extension. But the cohomology group in question depends on $\overline{f}$. So what does this mean? What particular element of the cohomology group is the obstruction? Or is it the vanishing of the entire group?
Second, I do not understand Mori's proof of this fact. First he reduces to the case that $X$ is affine, which I understand. Then he claims first that $\mathrm{Hom}_S(X,Y)_{\overline{f}}(T) \neq \emptyset$. He concludes by claiming it suffices to show that the restriction map $\mathrm{Hom}_S(X,Y)_{\overline{f}}(T) \to \mathrm{Hom}_S(Z,Y)_{\overline{f}}(T)$ is surjective, which is supposed to be reduced to the fact that the map $H^0(X_{\overline{T}}, \overline{f}^*((T_{Y/ S})_{\overline{T}})) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{\overline{T}}} I) \to H^0(Z_{\overline{T}}, \overline{f}^*((T_{Y/ S})_{\overline{T}})) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{Z_{\overline{T}}} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{\overline{T}}} I)$ is surjective. I do not understand what this map is, or why its subjectivity implies where the obstruction lies.
If the answers to these questions are too lengthy, I would equally appreciate advice on what sources to read in order to understand what is going on here. Thank you in advance. Here is a link to the paper in case it is helpful:
https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971241
